# Support Needed - Disassociated Xamarin account still thinks it is associated

Tags: xamarin, msdn, account, activation

I have an account that was associated with another business, but has been disassociated.  I have recently purchased Visual Studio Enterprise w/MSDN, and I am unable to redeem the Xamarin benefit because it tells me that my account is still associated with the previous business one.

I have verified that in the business account, my account is no longer associated and the seat it as using is not available (although the subscription has expired).

Can someone from Xamarin please help me correct this condition, I have been round and round with both microsoft telling me I need to contact Xamarin and Xamarin only pointing me back to microsoft.

Comment: I voted to close i\this as off-topic for SO. Maybe try at http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/, or at http://law.stackexchange.com/ if you're really hopeless.

Comment: Hi, sorry to see you're having trouble with this. Please send an email to my attention per our [support options](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/troubleshooting/support-options/#Summary_of_Support_Options) and include the email address associated with your [Xamarin subscription](https://store.xamarin.com/account/my/subscription). I'd be happy to help get this sorted.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because support issues like these do not belong on StackOverflow. Use the official support contact channels instead.